# Prestashop: No puedo Subir Imágenes de Productos a través del backend

Tags: prestashop

¿Les ha pasado que no pueden subir imágenes de productos?

Es decir, parece que suben pero la barra de progreso de queda congelada y la última no termina de cargar, si es una, esa no sube, si son varias, la última no sube e incluso a veces no sube ninguna.

Activo el debugger y da una respuesta n/a en el status code del uploader Ajax. De resto, no veo logs por ningún lado: php, apache, prestashop.

Los permisos los tengo bien 755 para directorios y 644 para archivos, es más,a través del cliente eMagicOne suben las imágenes sin problema.

Se tarda mucho en procesar la imagen, casi 30 segundos tratando y termina sin subirla, sin status de error, tal como se ve acá:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso sólo subí una imagen menor a 1mb, pero el resultado siempre es el mismo, sean cuantas sean, fíjate que no devuelve status code

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis configuraciones actuales son las siguientes:

- S.O: Ubuntu 18.04
- Prestashop: 1.7.5.2
- PHP: 7.1 con las siguientes configuraciones:

  - memory_limit = 1024M
  - max_execution_time = 300
  - max_input_time = 300
  - upload_max_filesize = 20M
  - post_max_size = 20M
  - max_input_vars = 10000
  - safe_mode = off
- Navegadores: Chrome, Firefox, Opera
- Caché: Memcached y caché de archivos, las he limpiado, desactivado e igual, el mismo error.

A través del cliente eMagicOne, se suben las imágenes sin problema.

¿Qué configuración o log me recomiendan revisar?

Comment: La solución a tu pregunta va en la zona de respuestas, por favor colócala ahí y no como edición a tu publicación,de paso tampoco le pongas solucionado al título de tu pregunta

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias por la aclaratoria. Corregido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice una revisión de los módulos instalados, que pudiesen afectar el comportamiento del módulo de productos y me encontré con el módulo [resmush.it](https://victor-rodenas.com/2017/04/09/optimizar-gratis-las-imagenes-en-prestashop/) de [wagood](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/user/20058-wagood/). Al desactivarlo todo funciona correctamente.

Ahora debo verificar si es un problema de compatibilidad en este módulo con la versión existente.